# Modx Revolution - New user cannot login

Tags: modx-revolution

I'm trying to create a new user in MODX REVOLUTION 2.3.0 but for some reason, the user cannot access the manager area. I tried to clear every bit of cache as well as to made sure the password is created by the system (email has been sent) and the user belongs to the Users Group.

Strangely, when looking at the user settings, it says that the user has made some 10 logins, but in reality, he has not.

When I type a wrong password, I get the wrong password error message, when I type a correct password, the input field gets cleared and nothing else happens.

Any idea how to solve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exactly. Like @proxyfabio said, he needs access to the manager. To at least asses if the user login works, give him temporary SUDO rights. If that works, work your way from the ground up.

Make sure an Access Policy Template and Access Policy is created. Make sure the policy contains "frames" and is checked at the Policy Template edit screen. Next, PLEASE, make a separate Role, like "Customer". Go into the Aministrator group (or again, PLEASE, create a Customer group) and head on over to the Users tab. Add the User to the group with the Role Customer - "your level" (I usually use increments of 500 or 1000). 
Under Context Access, add the user to the mgr context with the specified role and your Customer policy. Do the same for web if you with to avoid any in depth issues.

Finally, save your settings, flush your permissions, clear your cache and optionally flush your sessions table (you can also delete cookies for the browser you're using). When you've done all that, create an Incognito tab in Chrome or Firefox to avoid issues and try the login again.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that user don't have access to mgr context. Any user needs «frames» permission to get access to the manager.

Try to update user's data and make him a sudoer. It'll help to understand if wrong permissions cause the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have somewhat the same issue if I try login a duplicate manager user from an **android phone**, the login count goes up, wrong password gives error and correct password just refresh the login page.

However logging in from a computer works. Initially it didn't...

Here are my steps:

1. Duplicate manager user
2. Set new password
3. Login fails
4. Click forget login for e-mail
5. Login successfully (computer) with the new generated password
6. Change **original password** to original password!? :D
7. Login works everywhere except my phone